# Splitting long regex expression into multiple lines?

Tags: regex, powershell

Is there any way to split a regex into multiple lines so it doesn't stretch way past the end of my editor?

```
if (!($_ -match 'e_eld\.s|od_eld\.|oe_eld\.s|of_eld\.s|og_eld\.s|1c_eld\.s|2c_eld\.s|3c_eld\.s|4c_eld\.s|1c_eld\.s|o2_eld\.s|o3_eld\.s|o4_eld\.s|o5_eld\.s'))
{
    # stuff
}
```

When I try doing the below, it doesn't work.
Ive also tried surrounding it with `` and all the other tricks, but nothing seems to work and I couldn't find anything else about this (maybe my search skills are poor).

```
if (!($_ -match 'e_eld\.s|
                 od_eld\.s|
                 oe_eld\.s|
                 of_eld\.s|
                 og_eld\.s|
                 1c_eld\.s|
                 2c_eld\.s|
                 3c_eld\.s|
                 4c_eld\.s|
                 1c_eld\.s|
                 o2_eld\.s|
                 o3_eld\.s|
                 o4_eld\.s|
                 o5_eld\.s'))
{
    # stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **[`IgnorePatternWhitespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_IgnorePatternWhitespace)  regex option**, via its **inline form, `(?x)`**:

```bash
if ($_ -notmatch '(?x)
                  e_eld\.s|
                  od_eld\.s|
                  oe_eld\.s|
                  of_eld\.s|
                  og_eld\.s|
                  1c_eld\.s|
                  2c_eld\.s|
                  3c_eld\.s|
                  4c_eld\.s|
                  1c_eld\.s|
                  o2_eld\.s|
                  o3_eld\.s|
                  o4_eld\.s|
                  o5_eld\.s')
{
    # stuff
}
```

<sup>Also note that I've translated `!(... -match ...)` into the simpler `... -notmatch ...`; most [PowerShell operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators) have negated forms with `-not*`.</sup>

The **purpose of this option is to promote *readability* of regexes** by:

- allowing you to use **whitespace for human-friendly formatting**, without that whitespace becoming part of what is to be matched. Whitespace you do want to match you then have to signal explicitly, such as with `\` , `[ ]`, or `\s`.
- enabling **(single-line) *comments*, prefixed with `#`**; you then have to escape verbatim `#` chars. as `\#`.

A simple example:

```bash
# Yields $true
'foo1' -match '(?x)
  fo+  # word part
  \d?  # optional trailing digit
  $    # and nothing else
'
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest approach to achieve what you seek would be to use a multi-line string and remove the return carriage and new line character from the string.

The end result will be the same long string you had but it will allow you to break it vertically so you can avoid the horizontal scrolling.

```
$str = @'
e|_eld\.s
od_eld\.s|
oe_eld\.s|
of_eld\.s|
og_eld\.s|
1c_eld\.s|
2c_eld\.s|
3c_eld\.s|
4c_eld\.s|
1c_eld\.s|
o2_eld\.s|
o3_eld\.s|
o4_eld\.s|
o5_eld\.s
'@ -replace "\r?\n", ''


if (!($_ -match $str)) {
    # stuff
}
```

**References**

[About Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7) (`r`n)

[About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7) (multi-line strings)